# Return value inside a Asynchronous completionHandler

Tags: ios, swift

I have following method where i would like to return the `movieDestinationUrl` if SessionStatus is completed, however i keep getting this error `Unexpected non-void return value in void function`. What am i doing wrong?

```
func createVideo() -> NSURL {

    //  create new file to receive data
    let docsDir: AnyObject = documentsPath
    let movieFilePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("result.mov")
    let movieDestinationUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: movieFilePath)
    _ = try? NSFileManager().removeItemAtURL(movieDestinationUrl)

    // use AVAssetExportSession to export video
    let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    assetExport!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
    assetExport!.outputURL = movieDestinationUrl
    assetExport?.videoComposition = layercomposition
    assetExport!.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
        switch assetExport!.status{
        case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:
            print("failed \(assetExport!.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
            print("cancelled \(assetExport!.error)")
        default:
            print("Movie complete")


            // save to photoalbum
            return movieDestinationUrl

        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an observer variable and in it's didSet, save to photo album. In the completion handler, dispatch to main queue and set the observer to start the saving asap.

```
var movieDestinationUrlGetter: NSURL? {
    didSet {
        //save to photoalbum
    }
}

func createVideo() -> NSURL {
.
.

assetExport!.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
    switch assetExport!.status{
    case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:
        print("failed \(assetExport!.error)")
    case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
        print("cancelled \(assetExport!.error)")
    default:
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            print("Movie complete")
            movieDestinationUrlSGetter = movieDestinationUrl
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Synchronous: You need a hammer. You send someone to pick up the hammer from your toolbox, come back with it, and hand you the hammer. Meanwhile you are waiting for that person to return. Very simple, very inefficient because you spend all your time waiting for others.

Asynchronous: You need a hammer. You send someone to pick up the hammer from your toolbox. But you don't wait for the hammer to come back, because you have other things to do. When the person comes back with the hammer, they put it into a place marked "put hammer here!" and put a note "the hammer is ready" on your stack of notes. As soon as you finished what you were doing you see the note, remove it, and pick up the hammer.

That's how asynchronous calls work. They run to the end, they deposit their results somewhere where you can find them, and usually the notify you by calling a block of code that you gave them. (that's the "completionHandler").

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the return value depends on the success of the asynchronous code you should try using another approach such as delegate the response after the export is complete in the completion handler block:

```
func createVideo() {

    //  create new file to receive data
    let docsDir: AnyObject = documentsPath
    let movieFilePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("result.mov")
    let movieDestinationUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: movieFilePath)
    _ = try? NSFileManager().removeItemAtURL(movieDestinationUrl)

    // use AVAssetExportSession to export video
    let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    assetExport!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
    assetExport!.outputURL = movieDestinationUrl
    assetExport?.videoComposition = layercomposition
    assetExport!.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
        switch assetExport!.status{
        case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:
            print("failed \(assetExport!.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
            print("cancelled \(assetExport!.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed: {
            print("Movie complete")

            self.onExportComplete(movieDestinationUrl) // a method where you notify self that the export is successfully complete
        }

        default: { 
            print("Export did not complete")
        }
    })
}
```

Note that now this method returns void as there is nothing to return until the export is done

Also note that you did not cover all the possible status codes so the default case might also mean that the complete did not end successfully for other reasons. Use the 'Completed' status to make sure it is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return it because, since it's asynchronous, nothing is waiting to receive the value.

One approach is to use a notification instead and include the URL as part of the data attached to the notification.

Comment: How could this look like?

Comment: Look at the docs for `NSNotificationCenter`.  If using it isn't clear after that, let me know what part confuses you.